# How to convert Ant property into Ant resource?

Tags: ant, groovy

I would like to convert something like:

```
<property name='aoeu' value='a,o,e,u'/>
```

to:

```
<path id='ueoa'>
    <pathelement location="a/file"/>
    <pathelement location="o/file"/>
    <pathelement location="e/file"/>
    <pathelement location="u/file"/>
</path>
```

The value of aoeu could contain any number of comma-separated elements.

I can use the groovy Ant task, but not anything from ant-contrib.

So far, I have the following:

```
<groovy>
    properties['aoeu'].tokenize(',').each() {
        properties["ueoa-${it}"] = "${it}/file"
    }
</groovy>

<propertyset id='ueoa'>
    <propertyref prefix='ueoa-'/>
</propertyset>
```

which creates ueoa as:

```
ueoa=ueoa-a=a/file, ueoa-o=o/file, ueoa-e=e/file, ueoa-u=u/file
```

when what I really want is something like:

```
ueoa=/path/to/a/file:/path/to/o/file:/path/to/e/file:/path/to/u/file
```

How can I get this conversion to work? Alternatively, how do I create a resource in the groovy Ant task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked:

```
<groovy>
    ant.path(id:'ueoa') {
        properties['aoeu'].tokenize(',').each() {
            pathelement(location:"${it}/file")
        }
    }
</groovy>
```